# Textarea counter / countdown with negative numbers and enforcement

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, charactercount

I've been working on adding a character counter to a TEXTAREA field. There are many, many solutions available online for this task.

**"Stop-at-Zero" Solution**
The problem I'm having is that practically all solutions terminate user input at 0. That's effective, I guess, but it's not optimal in terms of user-friendliness. For example, if a user pastes text into the TEXTAREA, and the text exceeds the field's limitation, this stop-at-zero solution will abruptly truncate the excess text. The user then has to work to find the missing content and then edit their message, submit a second form, or some other burden.

**"Negative Character Count" Solution**
Other solutions allow the user to enter all they want. The character counter will go from positive to negative. The problem with these counters is lack of enforcement: They allow users to submit the form even with a negative character count.

**Twitter Solution**
I think Twitter has it right. They let users input all they want and highlight the excess text with a negative character count (and a colored background, which I don't need to have). They disable the submit button while the count is negative.

[image]

**My (Incomplete) Solution**
Working with third-party code I found through Google, I've devised a character counter that works perfectly in terms of the count. But being somewhat new to JS I haven't been able to code the enforcement part.

**Here's my question:**
How do I get the code to prevent submission of the form when the counter is a negative number?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">

<div>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit">
</div>

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form div {
    position: relative;
}

form .counter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: -25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc;
    }

form .warning {color: orange;}

form .exceeded {color: red;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

(function($) {

    $.fn.charCount = function(options){

        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {    
            allowed: 100,       
            warning: 25,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: ''
        }; 

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        function calculate(obj){
            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }
            if(available < 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
            }
            $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
        };

        this.each(function() {              
            $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
            calculate(this);
            $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this)});
            $(this).change(function(){calculate(this)});
        });

    };

})(jQuery);

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#comments").charCount();
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyc212/sk5kfopw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your plugin to take the submit button as first parameter.
If you want it to be more dynamic:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  form div {
   position: relative;
  }

  form .counter {
   position: absolute;
   left: 300px;
   bottom: -25px;
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #ccc;
  }

  form .warning {
   color: orange;
  }

  form .exceeded {
   color: red;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  (function($) {

   $.fn.charCount = function(btnsub, options){
   
    this.btnsub = btnsub;
        
    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = { 
     allowed: 100,  
     warning: 25,
     css: 'counter',
     counterElement: 'span',
     cssWarning: 'warning',
     cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
     counterText: ''
    }; 
   
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 
  
    function calculate(obj,btnsub){
    
     btnsub.attr("disabled", "disabled");

     var count = $(obj).val().length;
     var available = options.allowed - count;
     if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
      $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
     } else {
      $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
     }
     if(available < 0){
      $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
     } else {
      $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
      btnsub.removeAttr("disabled");
     }
     
     $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
    };
    
    this.each(function() {     
     $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
     
     calculate(this, btnsub);

     $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this,btnsub)});
     $(this).change(function(){calculate(this,btnsub)});
    });
   
   };

  })(jQuery);

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#comments").charCount($("#btnsub"));
  });

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post">

  <div>
   <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="submit" id="btnsub">
  </div>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try either by disabling the submit button using the `disabled` attribute, or preventing the form from submitting using `e.preventDefault`. I updated your fiddle...just uncomment either of the options

https://jsfiddle.net/sk5kfopw/1/

Comment: Thanks for this response. One glitch I discovered with the disabled option is that once the excess characters are deleted and the character counter is back in positive territory, the submit button remains disabled.

Comment: @mbnyc ah right sorry. You would have to remove the disabled attribute once if the character count falls back into the acceptable range. Here is the updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/sk5kfopw/3/